# About PHP Dig And Install

Tags: php

I am working on something and it is not working. I am getting this error:

```
Warning: include(../includes/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/install.php on line 24
Warning: include(../includes/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/install.php on line 24
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../includes/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/install.php on line 24
Warning: include(../libs/auth.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/install.php on line 25
Warning: include(../libs/auth.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/install.php on line 25
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../libs/auth.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/install.php on line 25
Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpdighttpvars() in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/install.php on line 27
```

Here is the code that it is getting the error:

```
   24. include $relative_script_path.'./includes/config.php';
   25. include $relative_script_path.'./libs/auth.php';
   26.
   27. extract( phpdigHttpVars(
       array('step'=>'integer',
```

Ok on line 24 where the include is there is a dot I put that in there cause sometimes it will help. But it didn't have one there before and I still had the error. I am not understanding why I can not get these to work. Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual file it is looking for is

```
$relative_script_path.'./includes/config.php';
```

One way to debug is to die with that path, then you can check what it's really looking for:

```
die($relative_script_path.'./includes/config.php');
```

The page should stop at that point and display the entire file path. You usually then see what the error could be.